# How class in swift works?

Tags: swift, class

actually i dont undersrand how class works

Example in playground: Class

```
class Check {
    var one: [String]? = []
    
    func append() {
        one?.append("test")
        one?.append("test2")
    }
}
```

Here i get 4 in console

```
var check = Check()
check.append()
check.append()
check.one?.count
```

Here i get 0 in console

```
var check2 = Check()
check2.one?.count
```

How should i use class to get 4 in example check2?

In practice i have viewContoller1 where i get data in array, but then i have to use this data 3-4 times in different ViewContollers but it is always nil

Thank you very much

Comment: `check2` has its own array, totally unrelated to that in `check`, that's how it works. You could make the array a static field, but I'm not sure it's the best way to share data between view controllers.

Comment: `check2.one = check.one`, I guess this is what you want for your view controllers

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're creating a whole separate object (check2) and it doesn't contain anything. You're just appending data in object named check and it doesn't have anything to do with check2. If you want to get 4 in check2, you need to append data in that object as well.